# File named SAT cannot be accessed nor deleted

Tags: macos, filesystems

There is one file on my OSX system after Catalina update (now Big Sur), that can never be deleted nor moved. The file is not even readable and the access flags are all "?" (see screenshot below).

What could be causing this and how can I remove this headache?

[image: The corrupted file screenshot]

Comment: Did you reboot?  Sometimes that releases the hold on locked files, even in the Trash.

Comment: @jimtut Yes, even did a system upgrade (Catalina to big sur). It does not help at all.

Comment: What does the output of `ls -la@e` print out?

Comment: Can you open the Trash in the Finder, and "Put Back" the item.  Then, use Terminal to change permissions and delete again?  Also, sometimes I've found that another acct might have better luck, if you can create another one on your Mac, and try the same Terminal-based permissions and deletion there.

Comment: @NSGod My `ls` does not have `@e` option. What does it do?

Comment: @jimtut I tried that. I can successfully move back the parent folders. But strangely, after moving them back, the SAT file and its parents are still there. In other words, the `mv` action produce somehow the same result as `cp` but they do not include the `SAT` file. Is it probable that something wrong with my SSD (corrupted hardware) causes this problem?

Comment: You mean the SAT folder and the Voicetrigger folder are still in the Trash too?  Now there are 2 copies?  I don’t think it’s the physical SSD, this sounds like a file system problem. I haven’t had to do much of this, but there are some disk tools you can try.  Is Disk First Aid still in macOS?  There are also Terminal tools (fsck?) to look at.

Comment: @Dogemore: `@e` should show ACLs and extended attributes, which I figured are probably what's causing the issues you're seeing. For example, if an item has the `com.apple.rootless` extended attribute, it can't be deleted. I'm confused by your `ls` not having the `@e` options; I'm not sure what to suggest...

Comment: Looks like it might be a `UF_DATAVAULT` file that might need some strange SIP-bypassing to delete:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/415598/108755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after I left my laptop a few months and it ran out of power.

There must be some mechanism that got reset after battery power ran out. So for those who might also experience this problem, try to power the laptop down for long period of time to see if the problem will go away.